# Replace TextBox With Dropdown List Dynamically In GridView When Edit Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 1 gridview to bind data from multi table (dynamic table). In some table i need to change textbox to dropdown list when edit row.
How to change textbox to dropdown list with condition?

**OnRowDataBound :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvForm.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    if (gvForm.HeaderRow.Cells[i].HasControls())
    {
        if (gvForm.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] is LinkButton)
        {
            LinkButton headerControl = gvForm.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
            string headerName = headerControl.Text;
            if (headerName.Equals("JenisMataUang"))
            {
                // some code to replace textboxt to dropdown list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GridView :**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvForm" 
    CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    PageSize="10"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvForm_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowEditing="gvForm_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvForm_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowUpdating="GridView_Main_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView_Main_RowDataBound">

    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewheader" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridviewrowselected" BackColor="#e7e7e7" />
    <PagerStyle BorderWidth="0" BackColor="#cccccc" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-13" title="Edit"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-save bigger-13" title="Save"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Save</span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-ban bigger-13" title="Cancel"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Cancel</span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-warning bigger-13" 
                        title="Waiting For Approval"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Waiting For Approval</span>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="alert alert-block" style="margin: 8px 8px 8px 0">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <p style="margin: 8px 0">
                Data is not found.
            </p>
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You need to add an EditItemTemplate to your GridView

Comment: My problem is I select from dynamic table (many table), and only some tables that need dropdownlist.

Comment: I wouldn't *change* the control, but use a `PlaceHolder` Control and drop in a TextBox or DropDownList based on your condition.   Where is the TextBox in your GridView definition? I don't see it.